# How to get Webkit for Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, python-3.x, webkit, gtk

I want to make a browser with Python GTK and Webkit for education purposes. I have GTK and it works, but I can't find how to get webkit for Mac OS X. I tried brew, pip3, easy_install. And I'm not sure if PyQT webkit port is the same as webkit.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install webkitgtk
```

You can use

```
brew desc -s string
```

to search for the given `string` in Homebrew.

Comment: but if I use import webkit with python or webkitgtk it doesn't work, because there is no module named "webkit" or "webkitgtk".. I tried this before.

Comment: WebKitGTK+ probably uses python-gobject; try using that instead. I wouldn't know otherwise, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For GTK3

`brew install pygobject3`

Otherwise

`brew install pygobject`